# Can you put .gitignore in subdirectory like config instead of root directory for structure reasons?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've ton of files that go into root folder and i'm looking to clean it up.

for example

```
.env
.babelrc
.eslintignore
.eslintrc.json
webpack.config.js
gulpfile.js
sequelize.json

... list goes on
```

I want to move all of them in config folder, because that what they are.

So is it possible to have gitignore applied from sub-directory to parent.

It seems like every tool wants to jam  its config file into root directory

aws, gulp, webpack, vscode, database, react, linting...

Comment: It seems like at least half of them could be replaced by config in package.json. Not sure if it's really the solution cause then package.json gets huge, but you definitely has less files if you put Babel and Eslint config in there, I guess the same goes for webpack and gulp.

Comment: i'll give it a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be technically possible or not (probably not in a robust way), but regardless, my answer is

## Don't.

The **root directory is really the right place for this stuff**, for several reasons:

- it just works, without brittle or complicated quirks,
- hiding configuration in some directory will make it harder to find for people looking for it (e.g. when something breaks),
- hiding configuration will make it even harder to even discover that the configuration files exist at all,
- it is just the standard place for this stuff.

You know, you just don't want people (especially yourself) to spend three hours on debugging some issue, only to discover that it was caused by well hidden config file, and that's the result I would expect.

**Hiding the configuration goes directly against the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)**, and this is a bad idea.

#### "But my files get lost between configuration!"

If your files get lost between the configuration files, then you are solving the wrong problem. You should just put your stuff in subdirectories, like `src`, `docs`, `test` or wherever makes sense for your case. That's the standard way and that's what people do (at least in JavaScript world, which is apparently your case, but it's really the same with any other language). Directly in the root directory live only configs, readme, and licence.

#### Put configuration in `package.json` instead

On the flip side, for the specific tools you mention the config can be generally contained in package file (`package.json`). So if the proliferation of files itches you as such, a simple solution is to move all possible configs there. The file will grow huge (it does anyway), but it may still be preferable to multiple files.

Comment: i guess ill move my whole app inside `app/` folder, that way only files at root directory would be configurations and inside `app/` there would be all stuff like node_modules, test, migration, controllers, views, public etc

Answer (score 2):

Very good questions, thanks for asking.

Currenty on top of my head I have 2 ways to tackle this problem.

### First: local

You don't have to use .gitignore to ignore files at all, and instead put your patterns in:

`.git/info/exclude`

### Second: custom ignore

`git config core.excludesfile ./config/.gitignore`

Which effectively solves your problem.

Comment: i didn't know about either one. i could see 2nd one being put in a shell script and be ran when someone downloads the project

Comment: Yeha, or just instructions in README.md. Also, if you add --global to config, this is how would you configure your global ignore, that's how I figure out it will work in local as well

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

Comment: Note that none of these solution will work out-of-the-box in freshly cloned repo.

Comment: true, some config settings are not applied when cloning fresh.

Answer (score 0):

If the bloat is only distracting you when writing in a GUI editor you can check if there are front-end plugins that only hide items from view without the monkey-business @Frax mentioned.

For example [make-hidden](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devine-davies.make-hidden) for VS-Code.